# If checkbox is checked, I want it to print numbers on excel

Tags: excel, vba

Please excuse my vocabulary, but I'm not an native english speaker.

I have 30 checkboxes on my userform and a "Register" button. Every checkbox is a client (from 1 to 30)

My idea is, for example, if I check client 3, 7, 20, and 23 on my userform and click "Register", I want to see the numbers 3, 7, 20 and 23 on a column on Excel with no spaces between.

As far as I know, I can only register the numbers to an specified cell, which is not what I want.

Here's an image of how I want the numbers on the cells (green)

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like you are new here. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways of getting what you want.

My first suggestions is to stablish a counter (a variable that increments for every checked box), so when you register the checked value, you register it on the Cell(counter). And because the counter variable is incrementing by step 1, you will not have any blank spaces in between.

For mor explicit info you can post your code.

Comment: I'm a total newbie when it comes to coding, so I don't have a code for this specific question yet ([this userform](https://imgur.com/a/ioRJ5sD) is all I have), and while I kinda get the logic behind what you're trying to say, I'm not able at all to write it in code. Please, would you be so kind to write it? I would really appreciate it.